# How to get the SOAP envelop from an simple XML output in C# .NET by using SoapFormatter class

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have the following input in FIX format (It may change according to the requirement). and I want to have the XML format in SOAP envelop. I used SoapFormatter class in C#, but getting the wrong output.

Input: 35=U149=GEMI18=FIX.4.19=73256=EMX

button_click()
{

```
Dictionary<int, string> rawMessagedictionary = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\u0001').Select(part => part.Split('=')).Where(part => part.Length == 2).ToDictionary(sp => Convert.ToInt32(sp[0]), sp => sp[1]);
richTextBox2.Text = DictToXml(rawMessagedictionary, "messageTags", "tag").ToString();
  string soap= ObjectToSoapMessage(richTextBox2.Text);
  MessageBox.Show(soap);
```

}

```
// Method to Convert object message to SOAP format.

 public static string ObjectToSoapMessage(object messageString)
    {
        using (MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            SoapFormatter serializer = new SoapFormatter();
            serializer.Serialize(Stream, messageString);
            Stream.Flush();
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)Stream.Position);
        }
    }

// Code to convert FIX message to XML simple format 
public static XElement DictToXml
           (Dictionary<int, string> inputDict, string elmName, string valuesName)
    {

        XElement outElm = new XElement(elmName);

        Dictionary<int, string>.KeyCollection keys = inputDict.Keys;


        foreach (int key in keys)
        {
            XElement inner = new XElement(valuesName);
            inner.Add(new XAttribute("key", key));
            inner.Add(new XAttribute("value", inputDict[key]));
            outElm.Add(inner);

        }

        return outElm;

    }
```

The Output as follows:

```
    <messageTags>
<tag key="35" value="U1" />
<tag key="49" value="GEMI1" />
<tag key="8" value="FIX.4.1" />
<tag key="9" value="732" />
 <tag key="56" value="EMX" />
 </messageTags>
```

// I am getting wrong output in

```
       string soap= ObjectToSoapMessage(richTextBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(soap);
```

as follows :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENC:string id="ref-1">&#60;messageTags&#62;
  &#60;tag key=&#34;35&#34; value=&#34;U1&#34; /&#62;
 &#60;tag key=&#34;49&#34; value=&#34;GEMI1&#34; /&#62;
 &#60;tag key=&#34;8&#34; value=&#34;FIX.4.1&#34; /&#62;
 &#60;tag key=&#34;9&#34; value=&#34;732&#34; /&#62;
   &#60;tag key=&#34;56&#34; value=&#34;EMX&#34; /&#62;
&#60;/messageTags&#62;</SOAP-ENC:string>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Why ?? the output is in this format..?

Comment: The ObjectToSoapMessage() giving me the wrong output as follows:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there are a few ways to fix this, one is to simply do a `String.Replace("&#60;", "<")` , `String.Replace("&#34;", "\"")` and `String.Replace("&#62;", ">")` which is more or less a band-aid. You can also use the [XmlTextWriter and WriteRaw() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8563xyxa(v=vs.110).aspx) which will prevent the escape characters from being output rather that their character reprenations